# Why the utf8 encode is not working in case of http get request?

Tags: node.js, xml, utf-8, encode

I would like to character encode a file, but it is not working. The file itself genereated by API GET request. It is a Hungarian language. I tried utf8 and the others but nothing worked. I also tried to read the file with encoding but without any success. What am I missing?

```
function apiCall() {                     

    const postData = `DateFrom=2022-11-15&DateTill=2022-11-15`;

    const options = {                                              
        protocol: 'https:',
        host: 'link.com',
        path: `/v1.1/Order/Find?${postData}`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Api-Key": apiKey,
        }
    };

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);

        res.on('data', (d) => {                                       
            answer += d;
            fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/logs/result.xml", answer, 'utf8');
        });

        res.on("error", (err) => {                                    
            reject(err);
        });

    });

    req.write(postData);                                          

    req.on('error', (e) => {                                      
        console.error(`Hiba: + ${e}`);
    });

    req.end();
};
```

The file contains several strange character.
eg.: fut\u00e1rszolg\u00e1lata => This should be: futárszolgálat.

Thank you in advanve.

Comment: "á" is encoded "\u00e1". If you display view the file in the browser, is it correct displayed?

Comment: That's standard JSON encoding, there's nothing strange about it. There is no UTF-8 here, though if you decode it, that's probably what you end up with when you serialize it again for writing to a file.

Comment: @Marc , Strange but browser can not open it. I little bit confused. Any idea how to save it correctly?

Comment: @Denes You could try the node.js built in string decoder.