# Why utf8 encode not working with filesync?

Tags: node.js, utf-8

I have data in file. When I want to read-out, the console does not encode it. When I just copy a part of it into my code and print it then it works normally.

Expected outcome:

```
var data =`
"PaymentMode": "CARDPAYMENT",
"GrossDeliveryPrice": "1999.00",
"GrossCODFee": "0.00",
"CourierName": "fut\u00e1rszolg\u00e1lata",
"BillingAddress": {
    "City": "P\u00fcsp\u00f6klad\u00e1ny",
    "Street": "Kolozsv\u00e1ri, 19\/1",`


console.log(data);

----------------

"PaymentMode": "CARDPAYMENT",
"GrossDeliveryPrice": "1999.00",
"GrossCODFee": "0.00",
"CourierName": "futárszolgálata",
"BillingAddress": {
    "City": "Püspökladány",
    "Street": "Kolozsvári, 19/1",
```

But instead I got a following result when read out the file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
  
const data = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/logs/file.txt",
            {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
 
console.log(data);

------------------------

"PaymentMode": "CARDPAYMENT",
"GrossDeliveryPrice": "1999.00",
"GrossCODFee": "0.00",
"CourierName": "fut\u00e1rszolg\u00e1lata",
"BillingAddress": {
    "City": "P\u00fcsp\u00f6klad\u00e1ny",
    "Street": "Kolozsv\u00e1ri, 19\/1",
```

Why it is not converted into the right format?

Comment: Like we already told you [the previous time you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74508071/why-the-utf8-encode-is-not-working-in-case-of-http-get-request), that's not UTF-8.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/logs/file.txt', {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});

const result = file.replace(/\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi, function (match, grp) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16));
});

console.log(result);
```

As this

```
const result = file.replace(/\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi, function (match, grp) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16));
});
```

Replaces/changes words after **\** to special words.